# inotitfywait list accessed files (once) no duplicates

Tags: linux, command-line, inotify

I am sure this is a simple question but i just cannot figure it out. List all files that (in any way) trigger an event defined in inotifywait.

My command is: `inotifywait -m -c -r $PWD > /tmp/file.csv`

Problem: When monitoring $PWD and starting a process that accesses this directory I get redundant information that files are accessed. It would be sufficient to know that a file was accessed once (no for each occurrence).

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to get `inotifywait` to do this - it would be be tricky because either the kernel or `inotifywait` itself would have to remember all the files that had previously been reported in order to avoid issuing extra events.

You will probably need to post-process the log, with `sort -u` or something, to remove the duplicate events that you are not interested in.

Comment: I have found this very fast solution for post-processing [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30178/26597)